# Is this true? $e^{ab^{2}} = e^{a^{b^{2}}} = e^{2ab}$

Tags: exponentiation

> Is $$e^{ab^{2}} = e^{a^{b^{2}}} = e^{2ab}?$$

I'm only really curious to know if the first term equals the second term, I just wanted to show my steps.

Comment: No; would you say $ab^2=a^{b^2}=2ab$?

Comment: Absolutely not.  Take $a=2$ and $b=3$, for example.

Comment: Note that $$e^{2ab}={\bigl({(e^a)}^b\bigr)}^2\ne e^{a^{b^2}}$$

Comment: Okay my bad, but how about this one? $e^{ab^{2}} = e^{{(b^2)}^a} = {(e^{b^2})}^a$. If $a$ were 1/2 then would we just have $e^b$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful because exponentiation is not associative. In general, if you don't write parenthesis, the convention is that they associate to the left, i.e.$$
x^{y^z} = x^{(y^x)} \ne (x^y)^z
$$
For your example:$$
\left(e^{ab}\right)^2 = \left(\left(e^a\right)^b\right)^2 = e^{2ab}
$$
is true, but $$
e^{\left((ab)^2\right)} \ne e^{\left(a^{\left(b^2\right)}\right)} \ne e^{2ab}
$$

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not. In fact if this expression are equal then we would have:
$$ab^2=2ab=a^{b^2}$$
but this is false for $a=3$ and $b=4$, so your hypotesis is false.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=b=1$. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

While $x+y+z$ can be grouped as either $(x+y)+z$ or $x+(y+z)$, we usually do not bother - because both refinements produce the same result.

However, with exponentiation, we have  $$\tag1x^{(y^z)}\ne\bigl(x^y\bigr)^z $$
in general (e.g., $2^{(2^3)}=2^8=256$ and $\bigl(2^2\bigr)^3=4^3=64$. Being lazy, we want to be allowed to write one of the two expressions in $(1)$ without parentheses. As it always holds that 
$$\bigl(x^y\bigr)^z=x^{yz}, $$
it would be wasteful to let ${x^y}^z$ stand for the right hand side in $(1)$. Hence, we agree to interpret $x^{y^z}$ as the left-hand side expression.

It seems that you fell for this trap and switched interpretations of nested exponentiation in your computation.

Answer (score 0):

You can say $\ e^{ab^2}$= $\ (e^a)^{b^2}, $ $\quad$ $\ e^{2ab}$=$\ ((e^{2})^a)^b$